# Function to change values of variables

Tags: python

I am facing following problem;
Let's say I have following:

```
a = 0

def something(variable):
    variable = variable + 1

something(a)

print(a)
```

The output is 0 instead of 1..

and if I use "global variable" line inside function, program shows following error:

> "name 'a' is parameter and global"

Any hints how to make this work? Or is it impossible in Python?

Answer (score 3):

Variables enter functions as parameters, and leave them as return values:

```
def something(variable)
    variable += 1
    return variable

a = 0
a = something(a)
print(a)
```

Comment: But I want function which changes value of variable, is this possible? So that my code's output is 1

Comment: No, it is not possible. You might find some weird way to do it, but it would be considered very bad practice in python.

Answer (score 0):

Python doesn't have the conceptual equivalent of `void func(int * a)` or `void func(int & a)` that can be used in C-likes as an 'in/out' parameter. While method arguments in python are pass-by-reference, all of the numeric types are immutable, and so the only way to alter a numeric variable's value is via an assignment, which creates a new reference for that name rather than altering the existing value.

The simplest way to alter the value of `a` from your example is of course to assign the return to the input:

```
a = do_something(a)
```

The potential gotcha with this is that anything that aliased `a` will not reflect the change, I.E.

```
a = 0
b = a
a = do_something(a)
print(a)
>>> 1
print(b)
>>> 0
```

To get equivalent behavior to `int * a`, you have to wrap the numeric value in a simple mutable data structure, like a list/dict, or place in in a class. Examples below:

```
class mutable_number(object):
    def __init__(value):
        self._value = value

    @property
    def value(self):
        return self._value

    @value.setter
    def value(self, value):
        self._value = value

list_a  = [0]
dict_a  = {'a':0}
class_a = mutable_number(0)

def do_something_l(lst):
    lst[0] += 1

def do_something_d(dct):
    dct['a'] += 1

def do_something_c(cls):
    cls.value += 1

do_something_l(list_a)
do_something_d(dict_a)
do_something_c(class_a)

print(list_a[0])
print(dict_a['a'])
print(class_a.value)
>>> 1
>>> 1
>>> 1
```

These forms all will work properly with aliasing, so if I had done

```
class_a = mutable_number(0)
class_b = class_a
```

And then at the end

```
print(class_b.value)
>>> 1
```

You get the expected output.

The other thing to remember is that python supports simple syntax for multiple returns via a tuple:

```
return a,b,c
```

And Exceptions are considered good programming style, so many of the use-cases for 'in/out' arguments in C-likes aren't really required (E.X.: Alter input parameter, return error code, or alter multiple input arguments in a `void`)